# How do I add two CollectionViews on one Viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

The end result is to have 2 collection views on one view controller. Both pulling from different sources as well as one should scroll horizontally while the other vertically.

Please advise on how to achieve this programatically.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I haven't used `UICollectionView` before, but as it inherits from UIScrollView, I'm taking a chance that it's pretty similar to `UITableView`.

When using one CollectionView, I'm assuming you have to set `collectionView.delegate = self;` and `collectionView.dataSource = self`, and in the `.h`-file, make sure your class is using `<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>` or something similar. When you're setting the delegate of the collectionView to your own view (`self`), you're making sure that the data provided for the collectionView comes from your own class, in the delegate-methods. I'm sure you already know this, as that should be pretty straight forward with one single collectionView.

When you are using two collectionViews, then you have to set

```
collection1.delegate = self;
collection2.delegate = self;
collection1.dataSource = self;
collection2.dataSource = self;
```

This will in turn do so that both collectionViews will call the delegate methods.
For instance, the delegate method `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` will be called twice. Once for collection1, and once for collection2.

To make sure they get the correct data sent to them, you should create a simple check in the beginning of every delegate and dataSource method, like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(collectionView == collection1)
    {
        //return cell for collection1
    }
    else
    {
        //return cell for collection2
    }
}
```

Here, I'm checking if `collectionView` is equal to `collection1` or `collection2`. The delegate methods are providing `collectionView` as the UICollectionView it is calling the method for, and that has to be either of the two. This can look suspicious if you have called one of your collectionViews for `collectionView` though, so be sure to name them logically.

Comment: You would want to change `if(collectionView == collection1)` to `if ([collectionView isEqual:collection1])` to properly test for equality, though.

Comment: No, == is correct (you are testing to see if two pointers point to the same thing)