# IOS UICollectionView throws assertion when using two collection views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have two UICollectionViews in a single UIViewController. I am separating them by tag number so that I can use the data source and delegate methods for both. However, when I run the code it crashes with the Exception:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}'`.

I looked this up in the forum and most people say you need to invalidate then reload the UIControllerView but in my case this is not working.

Anyone have idea how to fix this issue ?

Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    self.socialMediaGrayIcons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb-gray.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter-gray.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"insta-gray.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"sms-gray.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"email-gray.png"], nil];

    // setup collection view
    self.avatarCollectionView.tag = 200;
    self.socialMediaCollectionView.tag = 201;

    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.avatarCollectionView  registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
    [self.socialMediaCollectionView  registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"smCell"];

    // setup collection view layout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

    [self.avatarCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    [self.socialMediaCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    [self.avatarCollectionView reloadData];
    [self.avatarCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

    [self.socialMediaCollectionView reloadData];
    [self.socialMediaCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}

....

#pragma mark UICollectionView DataSource and Delegate mathods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (collectionView.tag == 200)
    {
        return self.children.count;
    } else if (collectionView.tag == 201){
        return self.socialMediaGrayIcons.count;
    }

    return 1;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell;

    if (collectionView.tag == 200)
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        Child *currentChild = [self.children objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        UIImage *curImage = [UIImage imageWithData:currentChild.thumbnail];
        UIImageView *thumbView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

        if (curImage != nil)
        {
            [thumbView setImage:curImage];

        }
    } else if (collectionView.tag == 201){

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"smCell";
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UIImage *curImage = (UIImage*) [self.socialMediaGrayIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImageView *thumbView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

        if (curImage != nil)
        {
            [thumbView setImage:curImage];

        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: There's some evidence here that your `numberOfItemsInSection` is falling through to the nonsensical `return 1` at the bottom and that one of the arrays has 0 elements.

Comment: Don't use tags. Simply store each of your collection views as properties and then compare the received collectionview argument against the property to determine which collection view you are being asked about

Comment: This [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371184/how-do-i-add-two-collectionviews-on-one-viewcontroller)  cover your question. hope it helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking @Paulw's good advice looks like this:

```
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionViewA;
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionViewB;
```

Your datasource methods have to be religious about always dividing in two branches of a conditional based on the collection view they were passed, and always using one datasource array in one and the other in the other.

You can enforce this religion by always getting your datasource via a convenience method, like this...

```
- (NSArray *)datasourceForCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    if (collectionView == self.collectionViewA) {
        return self.children;
    } else { // NOTICE - no else-if, there's no other valid condition
        return self.socialMediaGrayIcons;
    }
}
```

Use it everywhere, as in...

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self datasourceForCollectionView:collectionView].count;
}
```

Comment: How would I use the convenience method for - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath where one of the array's holds UIImage objects and the other Child objects ?

Comment: Get the array using the convenience method before the condition. Then reference the array at indexPath.row and cast that element as appropriate in each branch.

Comment: still same crash after making your suggested changes

Comment: Add an exception break point to identify the line. I'll be at a dev machine again in about an hour

Comment: I put an exception break point and it doesn't show the line .. it still breaks in main.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you comment out everything pertaining to layout and just reload data for both?  Same thing?

Comment: ok, so I took out these lines and it stopped crashing:   [self.avatarCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout]; [self.socialMediaCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout]; Why would the flow layout cause this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139860/discussion-between-joel-parker-and-danh).